# Why does a default argument for a lambda argument trigger a -pedantic" GCC warning?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

I had this lambda somewhere in my code:

```
[](bool a, bool=true){ return !a;} }
```

and GCC 4.6 "complained" with this warning:

```
warning: default argument specified for lambda parameter [-pedantic]
```

Which is mightily unhelpful when you don't know why this is "bad". I consulted the FDIS n3290 and didn't find anything in `5.1.2 Lambda Expressions` with regards to default arguments and a lambda.

<strike>**UPDATE:** I filed a bug report [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49326).</strike>

**UPDATE2:** OK, from now on I'm using `-pedantic-errors`. `-pedantic` only emits warnings, not errors.

Comment: I love the Final Draft International Standard standard.

Comment: @Tomalak: what a strange thing to say...

Comment: @rubenvb: he's just kvetching about "PIN number" syndrome, where the word for which the last letter of an acronym stands, is appended to the acronym. This is redundant, since "PIN" *already* says that it's a number, and "FDIS" already says that it's a standard.

Comment: (except come to think of it, it *isn't* actually a standard since it's not ratified. But it's a standard-like object, and that's what the S already means).

Comment: oh crap, thought I thought of that :)... there: fixed!

Comment: Why did this get the `[c++]` tag if it's clearly only C++0x?

Comment: @Xeo: because it's `C++`? I originally put it there, and justly so (though it was removed and added again). Just check all the "Related" questions at the right side of the web page, all lambda questions have both `C++` and `C++0x`. It's the same frigging language...

Comment: @Xeo: Because the tag-info page says so. :) Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b0x/info).

Comment: @Vitus: Heh, thanks for that, it seems I overlooked that one line while looking at the tag info sometime earlier. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Section 5.1.2 paragraph 5 specifically says that you can not have default values for the parameters.

> Default arguments (8.3.6) shall not be specified in the *parameter-declaration-clause* of a *lambda-declarator*.

Comment: Seems daft that this is merely a pedantic warning, rather than a flat-out error. Silly GCC.

Comment: Dang, must've missed that. GCC should make that an error then!

Comment: @Bo Persson, @rubenvb: I don't remember if compilers are supposed to diagnose per default ? I think there are so places in the standard with the dreadful "no diagnostic required", but I don't know what should be the behavior when it's not present.

Comment: @Matthieu - compilers are of course allowed to have extensions and accept code that isn't strictly according to the standard. Compiling Windows headers by default is a good idea for some of them. :-) With gcc I guess `-pedantic-errors` is what it takes!

Comment: @Tomalak: the standard requires that the ill-formed program be diagnosed. gcc has diagnosed it. If you want it to fail in addition to diagnosing, use `-Werror` or `-pedantic-errors`. `-pedantic` is documented "issue all the warnings demanded", if you wanted errors it seems "daft" to use the option that only gives you warnings ;-p

Answer (score 10):

Since C++14 [it is allowed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). It was found to be a defect long time ago: [Default arguments for lambdas](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#974), and also [Default arguments in lambda-expressions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1814).

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to have a default argument in a lambda function -- how could it ever be used? On the other hand, it does no harm, so why not allow it, after emitting a warning?

Comment: Yes, it does harm, in making your program unportable.

Comment: @Tamàs: I think TonyK meant that he finds it odd it isn't allowed by the Standard.

Comment: I don't know, I interpreted his answer as claiming the compiler does right if it only shows a warning for nonstandard code. Unfortunately gcc/g++ does enable GNU extensions by default, which I believe it shouldn't.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? I don't see the reason for this restriction, it can be useful, and there is no problem with implementation. For example, what's the fundamental problem with the original lambda: `auto lambda = [](bool a, bool b = true) { return !a && b;};`? You can write a closure by hand that will work just fine.

Comment: @Gene: Yes, you are right. I just tried it out, and it works. See http://ideone.com/pXHUk.

Comment: @Tamás, @rubenvb: I meant both of those things.

Comment: The place where I frequently want default arguments to lambdas is when using them as simple local functions. `auto addThingy = [](const std::string & name, int value, const std::string & extraSpecialText = {})`