# Lambda captures unexpected variables

Tags: c++, lambda

I was trying to figure out how lambda works in C++.

And something strange happened. It's so weird that I don't know how to describe it correctly. I tried googling several keywords, but didn't find anything mentioned the behavior.

I first tried [this code](https://ideone.com/zy0vEg).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std ;

auto func() {
    int a = 0 ;

    auto increase = [ &a ]( int i = 1 ){ a += i ; } ;
    auto print = [ &a ](){ cout << a << '\n' ; } ;

    pair< decltype(increase), decltype(print) > 
    p = make_pair( increase, print ) ;
    return p ;
}

int main() {
    auto lambdas = func() ;

    auto increase = lambdas.first ;
    auto print = lambdas.second ;

    print() ;
    increase() ;
    print() ;
    increase( 123456 ) ;
    print() ;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as expected as

```
-1218965939
-1218965938
-1218842482
```

However, after I add this into the 'func()'

```
cout << typeid( decltype( print ) ).name() << '\n'
     << typeid( decltype( increase ) ).name() << '\n' ;
```

like [this one](http://ideone.com/5shIHv)

the output became

```
Z4funcvEUlvE0_
Z4funcvEUliE_
0
1
123457
```

I did not expect to happen.

[UPDATE]

The variable `a` should have be "dead" because its life-cycle was ended.

But I'm curious why the code exams `typeid` and `decltype` cause `a` seemed to be resurrected?

Comment: On another note, `auto increase = [ &a ]( int i = 1 ){ a += i ; } ;` that default parameter should be verboten. Not sure  why it isn't.

Comment: @user4581301 I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35831564/5161420), though I didn't use `auto`.

Comment: Ah. Once again my knowledge is found to be out of date. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pure chance.**

As I suspect you know, you are printing unspecified values through a dangling reference.

- In your first example, the dangling reference tries to "read" from a memory location that has since been re-used for something else.
- In your second example, **the `cout`s and/or `typeid`s have affected the bloody guts** of the implementation of your compiled program such that the memory location of `a` happens to be untouched by the time you illegally print its value.

But there is *no point* in trying to rationalise about this any further, and you could get a different result the next time you run the program. Or your computer could explode. Or the timeline could be altered such that you had never been born. **Don't try to explain the symptoms of UB — just avoid it.**

Answer (score 4):

You are binding to `a` by reference. But this is a local variable which gets stored on the stack. It's undefined behavior to access it once the function finishes executing.

It's the same as if you returned a pointer to `a` and then started using it from the caller.

Comment: I think the OP knows this and that this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

None of the output from your program is "as expected".

The lambdas in `func()` capture by reference a locally-scoped variable that goes out of scope as soon as `func()` returns.

After `func()` returns, `a` no longer exists, like any other function-local scope object. As such their captured references are now referenced to an object that went out of scope and got destroyed, and any usage of the referecend value becomes undefined behavior.

Worse, the code also sets the value via the no-longer-valid reference. On traditional implementation, this will scribble over some random part of the stack, which can lead to the entire process crashing.

Comment: worse, it might not crash, it might instead overwrite a jump or return address, jump to random place in memory, which appears to call `DeleteFile` with some filename...

Comment: I think the OP knows this and that this doesn't answer the question. Mind you, mine effectively says "don't seek an answer to this question" which isn't much of an answer either :P